# how can i  get access to specifc tab in event create jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I need to make some changes in the tabs when the event it's create but i don't know how access of each tab inside of the event.

I tried like this but it doesn't work, i know that the problem it's the selector.

```
$("#menuContainer").tabs({
    selected : 1,
    create: function (event, ui){
        $(this).css('background','#54B2F1 url(images/ui-bg_glow-ball_75_53ade9_600x600.png) 50% 50% repeat-x');
    }
});
```

i'm also tried like this

```
$(ui.panel).css('background','#54B2F1 url(images/ui-bg_glow-ball_75_53ade9_600x600.png) 50% 50% repeat-x');
```

but the element ui doesn't have a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'this' in you create handler refers to the div used as the tab control wrapper:

```
<div class="ui-tabs" />
```

So the code that you have posted should change the background of the that. If you want to style the individual tabs themselves you will need to do something like:

```
$(this).find('.ui-tabs-nav li').css('background','#54B2F1 url(images/ui-bg_glow-ball_75_53ade9_600x600.png) 50% 50% repeat-x');
```

The create trigger is fired when the whole tab control is created. I think in this case you are looking for an event that is triggered when an individual tab is created.